# Поиск элементов в массиве по фильтру

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется массив типа string - WindowName, в котором хранятся строки длинной от 1 до 5 слов. 
Имеется текстовый файл в котором имеется список слов(каждое слово начинается с новой строки) - mask.Window_name. 
Я реализовал поиск на совпадения строк из текстового файла в каждой строке массива. Все работает.

```
private List<string> Mask(WindAndButt mask)
    {
        foreach (string s in WindowName)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, mask.Window_name, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                WindowforClose.Add(s);
            }
        }
        return WindowforClose;
    }
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы при написании, например, в текстовом файле текст вида "Error*" - поиск производился только в начале строк, "*error* - в середине строки", и так далее, как собственно и проводится поиск по маске?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Анализируй `mask.Window_name`. Если находишь в нем какой-то ключевой символ, то закладывай дополнительную логику. 
Можно так же в самом файле писать регулярные выражение и их подставлять в Regex.IsMatch